# Test that Bernoulli distribution has p=1 (i.e. non-random) from a sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bernoulli-distribution

I have a black-box function $f$ that may only return 0 and 1 for a given input. The function may be deterministic or stochastic for different inputs.

Assume I have input $x_0$

How many times do I need to sample $f(x_0)$ to conclude that the function is deterministic with at least a probability $p_d$?

The problem is easy if a sample contains both $0$ and $1$ (this means that the function is non-determenistic), but what do I do if the sample is all $1$?

From my understanding of statistics, my function is essentially is a Bernoulli distribution sampler. How do I test for $p=1$ given a sample of all $1$?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  See our posts about the [Rule of Three](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Rule+of%22+3).

Comment: @whuber I believe my problem is different. The rule of Three gives the lower bound for the $p$ with 95% confidence. I'm however interested in a little bit different question: how long do I need to sample $f(x_0)$ to make a conclusion that it is deterministic with a probability $p_d$?

Comment: Infinity is the answer.

Comment: The Rule of Three comes about because $-\log(1 - 95\%)\approx 3.$ It generalizes.  @BigBendRegion appears to have a different interpretation, though -- but I don't know what it might be.

Comment: He wants prove equality

Comment: There is also Bayesian solution involving prior on the point null. See Berger and Sellke, JASA, eg. around 1987.

Answer (score 1):

To give this problem some notational structure, suppose we stipulate that we have an observable sequence $y_1,y_2,y_3, \cdots$ consisting of function outputs $f(x_0) \in \{ 0,1 \}$ using repeated inputs of $x_0$.  We will use a Bernoulli model with $y_1,y_2,y_3, \cdots \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta)$ with unknown probability $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 1$.  Let $\mathscr{D}$ denote the hypothesis that the function is deterministic --- i.e.:

$$\mathscr{D}
\quad \quad \iff \quad \quad y_1 = y_2 = y_3 = \cdots.$$

One possible approach here would be to use a Bayesian model with prior probability $\pi_0 = \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D})$ and a beta prior $\theta | \bar{\mathscr{D}} \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$.  (We will also assume that if the function is deterministic then there is an equal chance that it is deterministic to a zero or one.)  Letting $s_n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ we then have:

$$\begin{align}
p(y_1,...,y_n|\bar{\mathscr{D}})
&= \int \limits_0^1 p(y_1,...,y_n|\theta) \cdot p(\theta|\mathscr{D}) \ d\theta \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{\text{B}(\alpha, \beta)} \int \limits_0^1 \theta^{\alpha+s_n-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta+n-s_n-1} \ d\theta \\[16pt]
&= \frac{\text{B}(\alpha+s_n, \beta+n-s_n)}{\text{B}(\alpha, \beta)}, \\[22pt]
p(y_1,...,y_n|\mathscr{D})
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbb{I}(y_1 = \cdots = y_n). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where $\text{B}$ refers to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).  We then have the posterior probability:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D} | y_1,...,y_n)
&= \frac{p(y_1,...,y_n|\mathscr{D}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D})}{p(y_1,...,y_n|\mathscr{D}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}) + p(y_1,...,y_n|\bar{\mathscr{D}}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathscr{D}})} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{\text{B}(\alpha, \beta) \cdot \pi_0}{\text{B}(\alpha, \beta) \cdot \pi_0 + 2 \text{B}(\alpha+s_n, \beta+n-s_n) \cdot (1-\pi_0)} \cdot \mathbb{I}(y_1 = \cdots = y_n), \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

which can be written in log-space (for $y_1 = \cdots = y_n$) as:

$$\begin{align}
\log \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D} | y_1,...,y_n)
&= -\text{log1pexp} \bigg( 
\begin{matrix}
\log \text{B}(\alpha+s_n, \beta+n-s_n) - \log \text{B}(\alpha, \beta) \\
+ \log 2 + \log(1-\pi_0) - \log (\pi_0) 
\end{matrix}
\bigg). \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

You can program the vectorised posterior probability function in `R` as follows:

```
POSTERIOR <- function(prior, n, s, alpha = 1, beta = 1, log = FALSE) {
  
  #Set log-beta functions
  LB1 <- lbeta(alpha, beta)
  LB2 <- lbeta(alpha+s, beta+n-s)
  
  #Compute posterior log-probability
  OUT <- rep(-Inf, length(prior))
  if ((s == 0)|(s == n)) {
    OUT <- -VGAM::log1pexp(LB2 - LB1 + log(2) + log(1-prior) - log(prior)) }
  
  #Return output
  if (log) { OUT } else { exp(OUT) } }
```